# Проблема при использовании Axios во Vue.js

Tags: веб-программирование, vue.js, frontend

Доброго времени суток.

С помощью vue.js пытаюсь реализовать приложение, которое будет отображать содержимое БД. Поискав подходящие компоненты, наткнулся на vuetable2. Из инструкции видно, что при его использовании в поле "fields" необходимо передать названия отображаемых колонок. Мой компонент vue содержит переменную fieldss, которая заполняется содержимым ответа с сервера (ответ выглядит так : "["ID","Name","Surname"]"). Обращаюсь к серверу я в хуке created, однако переменная fieldss не заполняется. Есть ли какие - либо соображения, почему так может происходить?

Заранее крайне благодарен за помощь, пример исходного кода расположен на https://github.com/RusProgrammer/VueTest/blob/master/Tablecontent.vue

**UPD1:** Также хотелось бы отметить, что если в методе created в его блоке then выполнить команду console.log(response.data), то в консоли можно увидеть ожидаемый ответ от сервера. Непонятно, почему за пределами блока then его значение попросту теряется.

Comment: наверное потому что у вас запрос асинхронный, а выводите вы `fields` не дождавшись ответа от сервера вне колбека `then`?

Comment: @overthesanity, а не могли бы вы подсказать, каким образом я могу дождаться ответа от сервера?

Comment: `then((response) => { this.fields = response.data; console.log(this.fields); })`, внутри этого же колбека

Comment: @overthesanity существует какое либо ключевое слово, которое заставит дожидаться ответа? Не могли бы вы привести пример на моём участке кода?

Comment: я думаю вы бежите впереди паровоза, начните изучать азы асинхронного программирования в js (колбеки | промисы), как это все работает и у вас не будет возникать подобных вопросов, не нужно хвататься за `vue.js`, `axios` и прочие библиотеки, начните с малого. cheers :-)

Comment: @overthesanity благодарен за "конкретику".